# Email and password match with instant user feedback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom-events, parameter-passing

I have a Javascript function that I want to provide instant feedback as the user is typing in their email address and password.  Both the email address and the password have email confirmation and password confirmation forms.  If the user inputs two emails that don't match, or two passwords that don't match, I want the hint to immediately show, and then go away if the user fixes that problem.

I was able to create working code, but I was hoping to make one function to provide the functionality for both situations, but I can't get it to work.  Here's my new code so far:

```
window.onload = function(){
    function match_handler(field_one, field_two, text_hint){
        console.log("field one is:" + field_one);
        console.log("field one value is:" + field_one.value);
        if (field_one.value != field_two.value) {
            text_hint.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            text_hint.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    //Test to see if the emails match
    var em1 = document.getElementById("em1");
    var em2 = document.getElementById("em2");
    var emHint = document.getElementById("emHint");
    em1.addEventListener("keyup", match_handler(em1, em2, emHint));
    em1.addEventListener("focus", match_handler(em1, em2, emHint));
    em1.addEventListener("blur", match_handler(em1, em2, emHint));
    em2.addEventListener("keyup", match_handler(em1, em2, emHint));
    em2.addEventListener("focus", match_handler(em1, em2, emHint));
    em2.addEventListener("blur", match_handler(em1, em2, emHint));

    // Then I have the same code as for the email, except 
    // for the password matching the password confirmation input
    // with function calls like:

   pswd1.addEventListener("keyup", match_handler(pswd1, pswd2, pswdHint));
}
```

When I console.log `field_one` I see there is an object, but then  `field_one.value` is blank.  I'm not sure what the problem is, but I expect there is a simple solution.  Any other suggestions related to improving the above code would be welcome.  JQuery is a possibility as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my own question.  Apparently, the format of my function call was not right:

```
var em1 = document.getElementById("em1");
var em2 = document.getElementById("em2");
var emHint = document.getElementById("emHint");
em1.addEventListener("keyup", function(){match_handler(em1, em2, emHint);});
em1.addEventListener("focus", function(){match_handler(em1, em2, emHint);});
em1.addEventListener("blur", function(){match_handler(em1, em2, emHint);});
em2.addEventListener("keyup", function(){match_handler(em1, em2, emHint);});
em2.addEventListener("focus",function(){match_handler(em1, em2, emHint);});
em2.addEventListener("blur", function(){match_handler(em1, em2, emHint);});

function match_handler(field_one, field_two, text_hint){
    if (field_one.value != field_two.value) {
        text_hint.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        text_hint.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

and voila, it works!